# Optimizing XPATH expression to search for a specific text

Tags: xpath

I am building a tool that detects automatically if certain best practices are followed based on the XML files uploaded to the tool in a zip file. This tool uses XPATH to parse the XML and identify if all the pre-defined criteria are met or not. One of the criteria this tools checks for is if certain objects (XML files) contain the function called "loggedInUser()". I am trying to accomplish this by using the XPATH below:

count(//nodes/node//text()[contains(text(), 'loggedInUser()')]) = 0

Sample XMPL file significantly simplified is as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<processModelHaul>

    <pm>
        <nodes>
            <node>loggedInUser()</node>
            <node></node>
            <node></node>
            <node></node>
            <node></node>
            <node></node>
        </nodes>
        
    </pm>

</processModelHaul>
```

The challenge I am running into is that the developer can upload a lot of these files and these files are significantly bigger than the sample I put above. So when I iterate over all the files and use the XPATH function above, it takes forever and I am running into timeout issues.

Is there any way to optimize the XPATH expression above to make this run significantly faster?

**EDITS**

The SQL query in MariaDB I am using to debug my code is:

```
SELECT
    `CR_getXpathOutput`(`RO`.`OBJECT_CONTENT`, `C`.`XPATH`) AS `CRITERIA`
FROM
    `CR_REVIEW_OBJECT` `RO`
JOIN `CR_CRITERIA` `C` ON
    `C`.`OBJECT_TYPE` = `RO`.`OBJECT_TYPE` AND SUBMISSION_ID=127 AND IS_ACTIVE=1 AND C.OBJECT_TYPE='Process Model' AND C.DISPLAY_VALUE='loggedInUser() detected'.
```

RO.OBJECT_CONTENT is the XML file and C.XPATH is the expression (//nodes/node[text()='loggedInUser()'])[1] which is coming from the table CR_CRITERIA. CR_CRITERIA is a reference data table where I maintain different XPATH. Here **CR_getXpathOutput** is a function defined as follows:

> CREATE FUNCTION `CR_getXpathOutput`(`ky` LONGTEXT, `xpath` TEXT)
> RETURNS TEXT CHARSET utf8 DETERMINISTIC BEGIN
> RETURN
> CAST(
> EXTRACTVALUE(ky, xpath) AS CHAR
> ); END

Comment: If elements structure above `nodes` is predefined, try to get rid of `//`, because it makes the engine search everywhere. Try this: `count(/processModelHaul/pm/nodes/node[contains(text(), 'loggedInUser()')]) = 0`

Comment: That did not work. It is returning me 1 all the time even when I am expecting it to return 0 for an object where I have loggedInUser().

Comment: Am I right that you want to check, if some file contains at least one element with the `loggedInUser()` string?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Try this: `count(//node[contains(text(), 'loggedInUser()')])>0`

Comment: Or even `count(//node[contains(., 'loggedInUser()')])>0`

Comment: This one worked but it is still not performing super well: count(//node//text()[contains(., 'loggedInUser()')]) = 0

Comment: How long? I've created a file with 10k `nodes` and on this file, the query works instantly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244857/discussion-between-pavel-koryakin-and-erick).

Answer (score 0):

**First:**
Change the XPath in your question to this:

```
count(//nodes/node//text()[contains(., 'loggedInUser()')]) = 0
```

So replace the `text()` from the contains-function by the `.`, since you are already in that context.

I would not use count and would do it the other way around. Just let the engine stop searching if you found one. Therefore it does not have to do al the xml.

If the xml-structure you are showing is always the same, meaning the text `loggedInUser()` will always be in this XPath: `/processModelHaul/pm/nodes/node` and that node does not have any other text then use this XPath:

```
(/processModelHaul/pm/nodes/node[text()='loggedInUser()'])[1]
```

If that node can be anywhere but will always have a parent nodes use this XPath:

```
(//nodes/node[text()='loggedInUser()'])[1]
```

If used in MySql/MariaDB you could try:

```
not(exists(//nodes/node[text()='loggedInUser()'))
```

Comment: Thanks Siebe. I would need to use (//nodes/node[text()='loggedInUser()'])[1] because the loggedInUser() can be present in children nodes within //nodes/node. I tried using it but when I execute the XPATH using the EXTRACTVALUE MySQL fucntion, it gives me an error saying there is a syntax error. Any ideas what could it be?

Comment: Could you show the exact query you are doing?

Comment: I added the SQL query to the question above.

Comment: Could you try `//nodes/node[text()='loggedInUser()'][1]` ?

Comment: It does not give me any errors but it does not return expected output. We want it to return a boolean of 0 or 1 where 1 means no loggedInUser() was found and 0 means it failed because it found a loggedInUser() function.

Comment: And `not(exists(//nodes/node[text()='loggedInUser()'))`

Comment: When I try executing that XPATH it throws an XPATH syntax error. I did try this string-length(//node//text()[contains(., 'loggedInUser()')][1])=0 and it is working but still not performing the greatest.